# How to make Irb not printing objects attribute

Tags: ruby, output, irb

I would like irb not to print my objects attributes by default. Is that possible? For example, I have:

```
class Test
  @tmp = nil
  def initialize(str)
    @tmp = str
    self
  end
end
```

and I get:

```
irb> t = Test.new("hello")
=> #<Test:0x18f6198 @tmp="hello">
```

I do not want to see the `@tmp="hello"` part.

Comment: Do you want to suppress that kind of output in IRB for all kinds of objects, all instances of the `Test` class or only that specific instance?

Comment: I would like to suppress that kind of output in all instances of the Test class.

Answer (score 5):

IRB calls `inspect` on the return value per default. If you want to supress or change that output in IRB just override `inspect` within your class.

```
class Test
  def initialize(str)
    @tmp = str
  end

  def inspect
    '<TEST CLASS>'
  end
end

test = Test.new('foobar')
#=> <TEST CLASS>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Or more generally you could write something like `"<#{self.class.to_s} Class>"`.

Comment: Sure, whatever the OP wants to show instead - only some attributes, a fancy string or just `nil`...

Comment: I will use `"#{self.to_s}"` ; showing all attributes was taking too much space in the REPL.

Comment: No need for string interpolation if you call `to_s` anyway. Just `def inspect; to_s; end` in then...

Answer (score 2):

Set the inspector string like the following:

```
IRB.CurrentContext.inspect_mode = IRB::Inspector.new(->obj{
  "<##{obj.class}:#{obj.object_id}>"
})
```

Then in irb, you would get like the following:

```
"foo"
# => <#String:47128160661240>
```

Comment: **This is the correct answer to the question stated**, btw. Monkeypatching the class is not.